# Force Close when i run this application

Tags: android

I am new to programming.
I'm creating a simple app which will handle my Button click event.
I have added the button using xml and linked it to the program, but the app force closes immediately after I run it.

Here is the code:

```
public class Sparkling extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    Button b;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        //actions....
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a peek at the logs or at least give us the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Without having any stack trace info, my guess would be Button1 is missing from or is misspelled on main.xml or something is wrong with your manifest file.

Comment: my guess is the button isn't being found so b.setOnClickListener is causing a NullPointerException.  We should start a pool!!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what had happened.

I was using:

```
android:name="@+id/Button1"
```

instead of:

```
android:id="@+id/Button1"
```